# sqlite3.OperationalError python

Tags: python, sqlite

so what i'am basically trying to do is getting data from a from developed with pyqt and insert it into a database, the problem is with my ID column,this is the code i'am using to insert the data to the database :

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO UTILISATEURS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ",(fullname,email,cin,address,phonenumber,ribnumber))
```

i always get this error :

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table UTILISATEURS has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied
```

when i enter a query to insert into the table directly from sqlite cli i get the results desired without needing to insert the ID it automatically autoincrements

here is the output of the .schema command :

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE ADMINSS(USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL,PASSWORD TEXT);
CREATE TABLE UTILISATEURS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,FULLNAME TEXT NOT NULL,EMAIL INT NOT NULL,CIN INTEGER,ADDRESS CHAR(50),PHONE INTEGER,RIB INTEGER);
```

Comment: Show the output of `.schema`.

Comment: i guess you need to pass the column name or else this might not work

Comment: your id doesnt seem to be auto incremented

Comment: the column is the ID which is my primary key , i don't need to enter it's name, i thought as i enter the other columns it will assign an automatic value for the id with autoincrement ,@DeepSpace i edited with the .schema output

Comment: isn't the primary key already means that the id will be auto incremented ?

Comment: No you need to pass (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT) when creating

Comment: gonna try it out now i'll tell you if worked

Comment: it didn't work either ,same error sqlite3.OperationalError: table UTILISATEURS has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied
 and .schema output : CREATE TABLE UTILISATEURS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,FULLNAME TEXT NOT NULL,EMAIL INT NOT NULL,CIN INTEGER,ADDRESS CHAR(50),PHONE INTEGER,RIB INTEGER);

Comment: did you try dumping the schema and creating it again? because even if you drop the table the schema will be there

Comment: you mean delete the whole database not only the table ?

Comment: yup try that once

Comment: didn't work , i keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a list of columns:

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO UTILISATEURS (FULLNAME, EMAIL, CIN, ADDRESS, PHONE, RIB) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ", (fullname, email, cin, address, phonenumber, ribnumber))
```

The only way to skip the list is to pass all 7 columns.

Comment: when i used your method i got this error : sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: That's a completely different question. What type your `filename` is?

Answer (score 0):

okay i accepted the previous answer but with a slight modification :

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO UTILISATEURS (FULLNAME, EMAIL, CIN, ADDRESS, PHONE, RIB) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ", (str(fullname), str(email), str(cin), str(address), str(phonenumber), str(ribnumber)))
```

this worked for turns out i should parse to string the values i got from my text box in the form.